# How can I concatenate strings in a cell array with spaces between them in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, whitespace, concatenation, cell

I want to concatenate (padding with spaces) the strings in a cell array `{'a', 'b'}` to give a single string `'a b'`. How can I do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can cheat a bit, by using the cell array as a set of argument to the sprintf function, then cleaning up the extra spaces with strtrim:

```
 strs = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
 strs_spaces = sprintf('%s ' ,strs{:});
 trimmed = strtrim(strs_spaces);
```

Dirty, but I like it...

Comment: `strjoin` is only available on Matlab R2013a and later so this solution is nice if you are working with an older version.

Comment: I have used this approach to manually print the dimensions of a variable as a string, e.g. "123x456x7", `size_info = sprintf('%dx' , size( var ) )` and removing the last char: `size_info = size_info(1:end-1);`

Answer (score 10):

matlab have a function to do this,

ref:

[strjoin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html)

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html

**strjoin**

Join strings in cell array into single string

Syntax

```
str = strjoin(C) example

str = strjoin(C,delimiter)
```

---

Ex:

Join List of Words with Whitespace

Join individual strings in a cell array of strings, C, with a single space.

```
C = {'one','two','three'};

str = strjoin(C)

str =

one two three
```

Comment: "strjoin" was first introduced in the version R2013a

Answer (score 7):

Small improvement (?) on the answer by Alex

```
strs = {'a','b','c'};  
strs_spaces = [strs{1} sprintf(' %s', strs{2:end})];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this using the function [STRCAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strcat.html) to append blanks to all but the last cell of your cell array and then concatenate all the strings together:

```
>> strCell = {'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e'};
>> nCells = numel(strCell);
>> strCell(1:nCells-1) = strcat(strCell(1:nCells-1),{' '});
>> fullString = [strCell{:}]

fullString =

a b c d e
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `join` and `strjoin` are introduced in R2013a. However, [the mathworks site about `strjoin`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html) reads:

> Starting in R2016b, the `join` function is recommended to join elements of a string array.

```
>> C = {'one','two','three'};
>> join(C) %same result as: >> join(C, ' ')

ans = 

  string

    "one two three"

>> join(C, ', and-ah ')

ans = 

  string

    "one, and-ah two, and-ah three"
```

Personally I like Alex' solution as well, as older versions of Matlab are abundant in research groups around the world.