# concatenating cells in matlab with delimiter

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

This should be very simple.  I have a cell array with two columns.  One is numbers, and the other is colors.  I want to concatenate these two columns into a single column separated by underscores.  For example, I have something like this:

```
plant_tag = {3,'dark_blue';3,'dark_blue';3,'dark_blue'}
```

and I want something like this:

```
desired = {'3_dark_blue'; '3_dark_blue'; '3_dark_blue'}
```

I've looked here and other places
[How can I concatenate strings in a cell array with spaces between them in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292437/how-can-i-concatenate-strings-in-a-cell-array-with-spaces-between-them-in-matlab)

Here's what I've tried so far

```
% Gives me errors
test2 = strjoin(plant_tag,'_');
test3 = strjoin(plant_tag(1,:),'_');
test4 = strjoin(cellstr(plant_tag(1,:)),'_');
test5 = strjoin(cellstr(plant_tag{1,:}),'_');

% No error, but misses number
test6 = [plant_tag{1,1} plant_tag{1,2}];
test7 = [plant_tag{1,:}];
```

I'm sure I'm missing something here--I apologize if it is something obvious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a vectorized solution:

```
desired = strcat(num2str([plant_tag{:,1}].'), '_', plant_tag(:,2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using [`strcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html?refresh=true) (and also converting the `3` doubles to a string):

```
>> strcat( cellfun(@(c)num2str(c),plant_tag(:,1)) , '_' , plant_tag(:,2))

ans = 
    '3_dark_blue'
    '3_dark_blue'
    '3_dark_blue'
```

Comment: Nice idea!  Works great for the example, but with all my data I get an error: 'Error using cellfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 37, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.' So I tried: strcat( cellfun(@(c)num2str(c),plant_tag(:,1)) , '_' , plant_tag(:,2),'UniformOutput',false)    but I still get the same error

Comment: That error will arise if the elements of `plant_tag(:,1)` are not all scalar.  You can try and get around the problem by moving `cellfun` to the outside: `cellfun(@(c1,c2) strcat( num2str(c1) , '_' , c2) ,plant_tag(:,1),plant_tag(:,2),'UniformOutput',false)`

Answer (score 2):

With a good-old for loop:

```
clear
clc

plant_tag = {3,'dark_blue';2,'dark_red';1,'dark_green'}

desired = cell(size(plant_tag,1),1);
for k = 1:size(plant_tag,1)

   desired{k} = strcat(num2str(plant_tag{k,1}),'_',plant_tag{k,2});

end
desired
```

Output:

```
desired = 

    '3_dark_blue'
    '2_dark_red'
    '1_dark_green'
```